# If statement based on which computer uses a script in R

Tags: r

How can I identify my computer in R?

I want to share a script with someone, but rather than having to comment out some stuff, I'd rather use something like the following:

`if (currentpc == mypc) print{"stuff"}`

Is there a platform independent, way (though I suppose information such as the platform could help in identifying my pc)? Preferably using base package.

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you explain why the code should behave so differently depending on who runs it?

Comment: Add `currentpc=mypc` to your `options()` in your `.Rprofile` file?

Comment: `Sys.info()`, `.Platform`, and `R.version` tell you some things that might help

Comment: @Matt Ball This is not an XY problem, but rather than hacking something together I figured there might be already be a way. It is about making sure it will only run for you and no others, also allowing you not to worry about has person "ZZ" loaded package "YX", and .Rprofile specifics.

Comment: @thelatemail Yea I was considering adding something to my .Rprofile, but isn't anything like this available already?

Comment: @GSee I'd say Sys.info() is definately useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any of:

```
Sys.info()[["nodename"]]
Sys.info()[["login"]]
Sys.info()[["user"]]
```

or other components of `Sys.Info()` (or some combination of them).

Answer (score 0):

Use Sys.getenv('COMPUTERNAME') to find your computer name

```
mypc=Sys.getenv('COMPUTERNAME')
```

Comment: Works on a Win7 box here, giving the same as `Sys.info()[["nodename"]]`

Comment: @thelatemail That environment variable is Windows specific.  Linux and Mac may have `HOSTNAME` defined instead.